# How to Formulate IF THEN Rule as a Predicate

Tags: oracle

I have a table with codes and processing dates. There is business rule saying if code = 3 occures 
on some day all codes = 1 on this day should be supressed.

```
create table test (code number , processing_date date);
insert into test values (1,trunc(sysdate));
insert into test values (2,trunc(sysdate));
insert into test values (3,trunc(sysdate));
insert into test values (1,trunc(sysdate)-1);
insert into test values (2,trunc(sysdate)-1);
commit;
```

I figured this solution. It works fine, but I'm extremly unhappy with the where predicate,
which is without the comment not realy intuitive for me. I'm sure I'll soon question the meaning of the predicate!

```
with codes as (
select PROCESSING_DATE,
CODE, 
max(case when code = 3 then 'Y' else 'N' end) over (partition by processing_date) as day_with_c3
from test)
select * from codes
where
-- if there is a day with code = 3 ignore code = 1
 (day_with_c3 != 'Y' OR code != 1)
order by processing_date, code;
```

Is there other formulation than this horrible !A or B, describing better the meaning of the business rule IF A THEN B?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM test t
WHERE
  code <> 1 
  OR 
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT null FROM test t1
    WHERE t1.processing_date = t.processing_date
      AND code = 3 
    )
 ORDER BY 2,1
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b4cf9/4

Comment: yes, this is an other formulation, but the negation and OR is sadly remaining. I'll probably have to live with it.